# How to add hook on golang grpc server start?

Tags: go, grpc

Is it possible to add hook just after Serve() method is called?

```
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(options)
if err := grpcServer.Serve(newListener("localhost:1234"); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %s", err)
}
```

I need to know when exactly its up and running to be able to call it from tests clients.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: i used telnet way, just re-checking until server ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found listener in server side about startup event; And I think there is no sense to listen this event, the right way is to telnet the server address and port in client side for waitting server ready.

Comment: Can you clarify why there is "no sense to listen to this event"? I think it would be especially useful when writing tests

Comment: @nz_21 Why need listen server self? Even test start after server startup, it should be test to watch server status, not server notify test.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.