# Golang grpc: how to determine when the server has started listening?

Tags: go, concurrency, grpc

So I have the following:

```
type Node struct {
    Table map[string]string
    thing.UnimplementedGreeterServer
    address string
}




func (n *Node) Start() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    thing.RegisterGreeterServer(s, n)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

In my main function I'll spin up mulitple nodes like so:

```
func main() {
    n :=Node{Table: map[string]string{}}
    go n.Start()
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())

}
```

The problem is, because I'm spinning up the node concurrently, there's a chance the dial up connection might not work because the node might not have been setup yet.

Ideally, I'd like a `done` channel that tells me when the grpc server has actually started listening. How do I accomplish this?

This is essntially the same problem as [How to add hook on golang grpc server start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65442028/how-to-add-hook-on-golang-grpc-server-start?rq=1) which doesn't have an answer

Comment: `Start` will block forever, or return with an error, thus, you can not get a signal to notify it has successfully started. You can only get a signal to notify it failed. The simplest way is to retry dialing with some threshold to exit.

Comment: The server started listening if net.Listen returns a nil error. You can send a signal then or pass the listener as an argument to Start.

Comment: Actually, if there's no error on tcp listening. It can be up very fast.
You can make a delay, something like time.Sleep(time.Second) before grpc.Dial()
For the point @Peter mentions is incorrect. Serve() will block until stop listening.

Comment: @HaiTH, nothing stops Start from closing some signal channel or whatever between calling net.Listen and srv.Serve.

Comment: @Peter because there's still a gap since tcp is up until grpc actually works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.Serve(listener)` blocks, so you can't achieve your purpose by having a done chan, instead you have to implement the [healthcheck](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) and readiness for your service, and check those before performing any request by the client.
The server should implement the following proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package grpc.health.v1;

message HealthCheckRequest {
  string service = 1;
}

message HealthCheckResponse {
  enum ServingStatus {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    SERVING = 1;
    NOT_SERVING = 2;
    SERVICE_UNKNOWN = 3;  // Used only by the Watch method.
  }
  ServingStatus status = 1;
}

service Health {
  rpc Check(HealthCheckRequest) returns (HealthCheckResponse);

  rpc Watch(HealthCheckRequest) returns (stream HealthCheckResponse);
}
```

For example, the [envoy proxy grpc_health_check](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/core/health_check.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-healthcheck-grpchealthcheck) works with the above proto.

Read [GRPC Health Checking Protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) for more information.

Comment: Are these interfaces in the grpc protocol? Are you talking more generally?

Comment: @nz_21 yeah, I updated the answer to providing the reference link. This health check protocol is somehow standard, and load balancers like envoy can work with that.

Comment: Do not implement it yourself, use the healthcheck package that's part of the grpc package

Answer (score 2):

The server can be Dialed as soon as net.Listen returns a nil error. Dial will block until the server calls [Accept](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener.Accept) (which will happen somewhere in s.Serve in this case).

Either move creation of the listener into the caller and pass it as an argument:

```
func (n *Node) Start(lis net.Listener) {
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    thing.RegisterGreeterServer(s, n)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    n := Node{Table: map[string]string{}}
    go n.Start(lis)
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
}
```

Or signal that the listener is up after Listen returns:

```
func (n *Node) Start(up chan struct{}) {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    if up != nil {
        close(up)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    thing.RegisterGreeterServer(s, n)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    n := Node{Table: map[string]string{}}

    up := make(chan struct{})
    go n.Start(up)
    <-up

    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I am wondering if the delay between `listen()` and `accept()` matters enough that it makes the channel signal less useful than it seems.

Answer (score -1):

For all those who are still looking for an answer to this, here is another simple way to do it. Start the server in a child routine. Here is a code snippet:

```
// Start the server in a child routine
    go func() {
        if err := s.Serve(listener); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to serve: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Server succesfully started on port :50051")
```

In my case I am using MongoDB as well, so when you run it, you get:

```
grpc-go-mongodb-cobra>go run server/main.go
Starting server on port :50051...
Connecting to MongoDB...
Connected to MongoDB
Server succesfully started on port :50051
```

I have also written a Blog post on this, with working code in GitHub. Here is the link: https://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2021/03/golang-grpc-microservice.html